# PHP Pushing array into a spessific key

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two 2Dimensional arrays,
**$array1**

```
Array(
 'week1' => Array (
              0 => '2015-06-29',
              1 => '2015-06-30',
            )
)
```

**$array2**

```
Array(
 'week1' => Array (
              0 => '2015-07-01',
              1 => '2015-07-02',
              2 => '2015-07-03',
              3 => '2015-07-04',
              4 => '2015-07-05',
            ),
 'week2' => Array (
              0 => '2015-07-06',
              1 => '2015-07-07',
              2 => '2015-07-08',
              3 => '2015-07-09',
              4 => '2015-07-10',
              5 => '2015-07-11',
              6 => '2015-07-12',
            ),
)
```

And this is my expected result,

```
Array(
 'week1' => Array (
              0 => '2015-06-29',
              1 => '2015-06-30',
              2 => '2015-07-01',
              3 => '2015-07-02',
              4 => '2015-07-03',
              5 => '2015-07-04',
              6 => '2015-07-05',
            ),
 'week2' => Array (
              0 => '2015-07-06',
              1 => '2015-07-07',
              2 => '2015-07-08',
              3 => '2015-07-09',
              4 => '2015-07-10',
              5 => '2015-07-11',
              6 => '2015-07-12',
            ),
)
```

i have been trying to use array_push but the array become 3 dimensional instead of joining the same key name. Could you guys halp me out?
Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use array_merge_recursive (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Just:

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2)
```

Comment: Make sure to read which array overwrites the other in the docs

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much for your help. :D

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your array, which you want to add and use the key to [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the array, e.g.

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $v)
    $array2[$k] = array_merge($array2[$k], $v);
```